# QR code detecting in python with OpenCV raises UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, opencv, qr-code

I have written a class to retrieve creditor data like the Iban from an invoice pdf with an qr code on it.
It worked fine, until we've gotten an pdf that throws this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 157: invalid start byte
```

If I try to process the pdf.

That is how I've done it:

```
doc = fitz.open(self.image_path)  # open document
i = 0

if not os.path.exists(f"./qr_codes/"):
    os.makedirs(f"./qr_codes/")

for page in doc:
    pix = page.get_pixmap(matrix=self.mat)  # render page to an image
    pix.save(f"./qr_codes/page_{i}.png")

    img = cv2.imread(f"./qr_codes/page_{i}.png")
    detect = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
    text, points, straight_qrcode = detect.detectAndDecode(img)

    if text:
        # try to find a IBAN in one of the lines
        self.iban = "\r\n".join([line for line in text.splitlines() if re.findall(r"CH\d{19}", line.strip())])
        # try to find the reference number by joining all lines and searching for CH QRR \d+
        # Also replace the CH QRR Stuff, because only the number is needed for SAP
        ref_number = re.findall(r'CH\s*QRR\s*\d+|$', " ".join(text.splitlines()))
        self.ref_number = int(re.sub(r"\D","", ref_number[0])) if ref_number else None
        self.__save_values()
        return True
    i += 1
return False
```

Is there a way to strip the bytes somehow?

I've tried it via numpy array also:

```
    stream = open(f'./qr_codes/page_{i}.png', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore")
    stream = bytearray(stream.read(), encoding="utf-8")
    detect = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
    text, points, straight_qrcode = detect.detectAndDecode(numpy.asarray(stream, dtype=numpy.uint8))
    # print(text)
```

But this way I only retrieve an empty text instead, so I'm doing something wrong this way I guess.
Could someone provide some ideas on how to solve the byte issue?

**Edit:**
As asked, the full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\m7073\Repos\Chronos_New\invoice_extraction\qr_code_scan.py", line 128, in <module>
    qrcode.set_qr_values()
  File "C:\Users\m7073\Repos\Chronos_New\invoice_extraction\qr_code_scan.py", line 73, in set_qr_values
    text, points, straight_qrcode = detect.detectAndDecode(img)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 157: invalid start byte
```

**Edit 2(minimal reproducable example):**

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(f"page_1.png")
detect = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
text, points, straight_qrcode = detect.detectAndDecode(img)
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: @KlausD. done, hope it helps to clarify things

Comment: [mre] required. reduce the entire problem down to loading a picture of a QR code, with opencv, and provide that exact picture. remove all the "fitz" stuff. if it turns out that the error _requires_ "fitz", that would be interesting, but I doubt it. -- this *could* be a bug in opencv. make sure you use the latest release, which is currently 4.7.0

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I've added a excecutable code and the invoice image (even though I don't see it in the OP?!)

Comment: excellent. I can reproduce the issue. that's definitely worth a bug report. you should file one at https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues (include that picture or any picture that provokes the exception, and the simple MRE). the picture decodes fine with my smartphone. I see two possibilities: either the opencv code falsely tries to decode something that isn't utf8, or the code falsely declares something to be utf8 when it isn't.

Comment: oh, appears to exist already: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22131 was closed without resolution (except recommendation to use a different decoder library...) you should just open a new issue about this.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as alternative for this package? Something that runs without any external dependencies? That would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late reply because I was ill for 3 weeks, but I've switched to zxingcpp and adjusted the code from:

```
for page in doc:
    pix = page.get_pixmap(matrix=self.mat)  # render page to an image
    pix.save(f"./qr_codes/page_{i}.png")

    img = cv2.imread(f"./qr_codes/page_{i}.png")
    detect = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
    text, points, straight_qrcode = detect.detectAndDecode(img)

    if text:
        # try to find a IBAN in one of the lines
        self.iban = "\r\n".join([line for line in text.splitlines() if re.findall(r"CH\d{19}", line.strip())])
        # try to find the reference number by joining all lines and searching for CH QRR \d+
        # Also replace the CH QRR Stuff, because only the number is needed for SAP
        ref_number = re.findall(r'CH\s*QRR\s*\d+|$', " ".join(text.splitlines()))
        self.ref_number = int(re.sub(r"\D","", ref_number[0])) if ref_number else None
        self.__save_values()
        return True
    i += 1
```

to:

```
for page in pdf:
    pil_image = page.render(scale=3).to_pil()
    pil_image.save(f"./qr_codes/page_{i}.png")
    img = cv2.imread(f"./qr_codes/page_{i}.png")

    for result in zxingcpp.read_barcodes(img):
        # try to find a IBAN in one of the lines
        self.iban = "\r\n".join([line for line in result.text.splitlines() if re.findall(r"CH\d{19}", line.strip())])
        # try to find the reference number by joining all lines and searching for CH QRR \d+
        # Also replace the CH QRR Stuff, because only the number is needed for SAP
        ref_number = re.findall(r'CH\s*QRR\s*\d+|$', " ".join(result.text.splitlines()))
        self.ref_number = int(re.sub(r"\D", "", ref_number[0])) if ref_number else None
        self.__save_values()
        return True
    i += 1
```

And this way it works.

Simple example to get it going:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(f"./qr_codes/page_1.png")
detect = cv2.QRCodeDetector(
# iterate over QR Codes
for result in zxingcpp.read_barcodes(img):
    print(result.text)
```

**Edit:**
I had troubles getting the zxingcpp module to work on the amazone linux server we're using.
I solved it this way:

```
 yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
 pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
 yum install python3-devel.x86_64
 pip install zxing-cpp
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue may be with `utf-8`
Python has many standard encodings and `utf-8` is the default one as it works with most bytes. However there are exceptions and I think you program hit one.
I think a simple solution here is to use the `utf-16` encoding as such

```
stream = bytearray(stream.read(), encoding="utf-8")
```

I would also recommend *always* specifying the encoding as windows has a different default encoding so a windows user running a program that works on Linux may not always be successful

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. That didn't work either, if I do it this way I get a UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM error, and if I use utf-16-le instead (mentioned in another question) I still get an empty text from the qr code ;(

Comment: the error seems to be caused from *within* an opencv API. these suggestions can't affect that.

Comment: I see you're using windows. I suspect the file is not encoded in utf-8 at all, but instead with `ISO-8859-1` You might want to try to specify that as the encoding type.

Comment: @Egeau we're talking about a library that decodes QR codes. that has nothing to do with the operating system or the encoding of the python script source code.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz, I see that this is clear now in the question, but it was not when I answered it. Then, it was just stating that there was *a* decode error, so I thought this'd help, tough I understand I made the wrong presumptions now on reading the heavily modified question. :P

Comment: the traceback already pointed to `detect.detectAndDecode(img)`